# Bind/apply filter with checkboxes created in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

I have a `ListView` with many `MovieItem`s inside it. The `ListView` is bind to "FtMainList":

```
    ObservableCollection<MovieItem> MainList = new ObservableCollection<MoviItem>();
    public ICollectionView FtMainList
    {
        get
        {
            var source = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainList);
            source.Filter = a => ListStatusFilter((MovieItem)a);
            return source;
        }
    }
```

A few days ago i created a filter for them:

[image: Filter by status]

```
        private bool ListStatusFilter(MovieItem movie)
    {
        return (LvFilter_Watching.IsChecked.HasValue && LvFilter_Watching.IsChecked.Value && movie.lMyStatus == "Watching") ||
               (LvFilter_OnHold.IsChecked.HasValue && LvFilter_OnHold.IsChecked.Value && movie.lMyStatus == "On-Hold") ||
               (LvFilter_PlanToWatch.IsChecked.HasValue && LvFilter_PlanToWatch.IsChecked.Value && movie.lMyStatus == "Plan To Watch") ||
               (LvFilter_Dropped.IsChecked.HasValue && LvFilter_Dropped.IsChecked.Value && movie.lMyStatus == "Dropped") ||
               (LvFilter_Completed.IsChecked.HasValue && LvFilter_Completed.IsChecked.Value && movie.lMyStatus == "Completed");
    }
```

Those are Two-state CheckBoxes. So if i checked "Completed", the `ListView` will show all "completed movies". Otherwise, all completed movies will be hidden, and vice versa. It works as expected.

But, i dont want to stop there, i want to create more filter. Now i want to filter them by "Genre". The problem is, there are 26 genres (probably increasing), and i'm to lazy (lol) to create 26 checkboxes and their filters. So i have an idea:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GenericList3StateCheckbox">
        <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" Checked="FilterChanged" Unchecked="FilterChanged" Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{x:Null}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
...
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Text="Genre" Margin="0,0,0,10" Panel.ZIndex="1" Foreground="White" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Ebrima" TextDecorations="Underline" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="LvFilter_Genres" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GenericList3StateCheckbox}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Height="130"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
            List<string> LvGenres = new List<string>();             
            foreach (MovieItem ame in MainList)
            {
                string[] spt = ame.gGenres.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (string gen in spt)
                {
                    bool isDuplicate = false;
                    foreach (string chk in LvGenres)
                    {
                        if (chk == gen)
                        {
                            isDuplicate = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isDuplicate == false)
                    {
                        LvGenres.Add(gen);
                    }
                }
             }
             LvGenres.Sort();
             LvFilter_Genres.ItemsSource = LvGenres;
```

Result:

[image: Filter by genre]

Unlike those above, these Checkboxes are 3-state. So if i checked "Action", the `ListView` will ONLY show movies which contains "Action" genre. If it is Null(a.k.a Intermediate), the `ListView` may show movie that doesn't contain "Action" genre. If it is Unchecked, all movies that doesn't contain "Action" genre will be hidden.

Now for the question, what should i do so these checkboxes will works as expected?

FYI, `MovieItem` class:

```
public class MovieItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Genres { get; set; }
   public int Duration { get; set; }
   public string lMyStatus { get; set; }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

`Genres` is a single string contains some "genre" separated with coma and space. example: "Action, Thriller, Documenter"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use custom View Model for ListBox item instead of a string. In that case you'll have more flexibility to implement whatever you want.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GenericList3StateCheckbox">
    <CheckBox IsThreeState="True" Checked="FilterChanged" Unchecked="FilterChanged" Content="{Binding Caption}" IsChecked="{Binding State}"/>
</DataTemplate>


List<FilterItemVM> LvGenres = new List<FilterItemVM>();

public class FilterItemVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _caption;
    public string Caption
    {
        get { return _caption; }
        set
        {
            _caption= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool? _state;
    public bool? State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            _state= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}


private bool ListStatusFilter(MovieItem movie)
{
    List<string> itemGengres = movie.Genres.Split(',').Select(g => g.Trim()).ToList();

    List<string> obligatoryGengres = LvGenres.Where(fi => fi.State.HasValue && fi.State.Value == true).Select(fi => fi.Caption).ToList();
    List<string> forbiddenGengres = LvGenres.Where(fi => fi.State.HasValue && fi.State.Value == false).Select(fi => fi.Caption).ToList();

    bool isGenresMatched = obligatoryGengres.All(g => itemGengres.Contains(g)) && !forbiddenGengres.Any(g => itemGengres.Contains(g));

    return isGenresMatched && (LvFilter_Watching.IsChecked.HasValue && LvFilter_Watching.IsChecked.Value && movie.lMyStatus == "Watching") ||
           (LvFilter_OnHold.IsChecked.HasValue && LvFilter_OnHold.IsChecked.Value && movie.lMyStatus == "On-Hold") ||
           (LvFilter_PlanToWatch.IsChecked.HasValue && LvFilter_PlanToWatch.IsChecked.Value && movie.lMyStatus == "Plan To Watch") ||
           (LvFilter_Dropped.IsChecked.HasValue && LvFilter_Dropped.IsChecked.Value && movie.lMyStatus == "Dropped") ||
           (LvFilter_Completed.IsChecked.HasValue && LvFilter_Completed.IsChecked.Value && movie.lMyStatus == "Completed");
}
```

Comment: Always getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: In first version of my answer there was C# 6 synax with null propagaion operator: PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...). In other case event handler should be checked for null.

Comment: I applied your suggestion to my app. What's next?

Comment: In your ListStatusFilter function check if MovieItem satisfies to the state that is set by collection of FilterItemVM. Please add code for MovieItem, because it is hard to say how you've implemented Genre property.

Comment: Updated the answer. The main idea that you have to check if all of obligatory items are present in your genres string and no one from forbidden list.

Comment: Haha, I just solved my problem with similar way. But this is more simple. Thx so much :D

Comment: You are welcome :) It is also possible to use Except and Intersect methods for this for better readability, e.g.: !obligatoryGengres.Except(itemGengres).Any() && !forbiddenGengres.Intersect(itemGengres).Any();